# Is there a law of cosine for n-dimensional hyperbolic simplex

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, trigonometric-polynomials

We know that, given an n-dimensional Euclidean simplex, for all $1\leq i,j,k,l\leq n+1$, we have(law of sines)$$\frac{A_i A_j}{A_k A_l}=\frac{c_{ij}}{c_{kl}}$$(from *Elementary Formulas for a Hyperbolic Tetrahedron*)
And in http://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/106_03_JIPAM/106_03.pdf it mentioned some inequalities for simplexes in Euclidean space.

I wonder if there is a formula about law of sines and cosines for hyperbolic n-simplexes which only have terms: side lengths, area, dihedral angles.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, something like that is proved in the paper by Simon Kokkendorff:

*Kokkendorff, Simon L.*, [**Polar duality and the generalized law of sines**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00022-006-1858-7), J. Geom. 86, No. 1-2, 140-149 (2006). [ZBL1115.51010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1115.51010).

It would be too cumbersome to define everything here, but the paper is very nicely written.